# How to get notification subtitle/body using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to read macOS notifications title and subtitle using AppleScript. I managed to get the title using the example posted [here](https://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/notifications/01A.html) (number 5), but I also need to get the subtitle.

Here is the code that returns the title:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Notification Center"
            set theseWindows to every window
            set theseTitles to {}
            repeat with thisWindow in theseWindows
                try
                    set thisTitle to the value of static text 1 of thisWindow
                    set the end of theseTitles to thisTitle
                end try
            end repeat
            return theseTitles
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Does anyone know how I can get the notification subtitle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor**:

```
display notification "Body Text Line" with title "Title Text Line" subtitle "Subtitle Text Line"
```

Produces this notification:

[image]

Then running the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor**:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "NotificationCenter"
        get value of static text 1 of window 1
        get value of static text 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
        get value of static text 2 of scroll area 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Shows the following output in the **Replies** pane of **Script Editor**:

```
tell application "System Events"
    get value of static text 1 of window 1 of application process "NotificationCenter"
        --> "Title Text Line"
    get value of static text 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "NotificationCenter"
        --> "Subtitle Text Line"
    get value of static text 2 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "NotificationCenter"
        --> "Body Text Line"
end tell
```

As you can see, it's the `get value of static text 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1` which returns the **subtitle**.

Comment: I get this error when running your applescript in ventura error "System Events got an error: Can’t get static text 1 of window 1 of application process \"NotificationCenter\". Invalid index." number -1719 from static text 1 of window 1 of application process "NotificationCenter"

Comment: this no longer works on recent MacOS versions

Comment: @Rosenpin For macOS Ventura: 
`return value of static text 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Notification Center" of application process "NotificationCenter"`
Where static text 1-3 are title, subtitle and body, and group 1-n is the notification.
Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/Ptujec/LaunchBar/blob/master/Notifications/Dismiss%20all%20notifications.lbaction/Contents/Scripts/default.applescript)